# BCP export queryout error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, bcp

In Sql Server 2000, connected using osql command line, connected through a DSN ODBC, Using the OLEDB Provider, I am trying to export the result of a Stored Procedure to an XML file. However I get and error no matter how far down I simplify the query.

if I use the OUT qualifer I get the following error:

> Msg 179, Level 15, State 1, Server SERVER, Line 1
>   Cannot use the OUTPUT option when passing a constant to a stored procedure.

which from my reading is expected. but no matter how I use QUERYOUT I get following error:

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Server SERVER, Line 1
>   Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'.

Here is the simplest query I can muster and I still get this error:

`bcp "Select * FROM [SERVER].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]" queryout \\fileserver\test.txt -c -T`

Comment: I thought osql had it's own switches? So BCP won't work in this way: "osql /q "Select * FROM [SERVER].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]" /o \\fileserver\test.txt

Comment: I can honestly say I don't know. if it helps any, my end goal is a sql insert trigger that exports data to an XML document. If there is a better tool to do that, Then I have no objection to using that instead

Comment: bcp does not support UNC paths

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a text file such as 
set nocount on
select * from table
and save it. Let say it is in c:(input_text).txt

Then, in SQL server management studio, create and run following osql query to get output_text.

osql -U (login id) -P (password) -S (server name) -d (db name) -i c:(input_text).txt -o c:(output_text).txt -h-1 -s " " -n -w 2000